# Thread safe method invocation

Tags: multithreading, object, thread-safety, c#-3.0

Please let me know below method invocation is thread safe or not.
I am calling ThreadStartMain on my main thread and create new threads and invoke A_GetCounryName method on new instance.

Since i am always calling via new instance i think this is thread safe even though i am having instance variables in some classes.

```
 class MyThread
    {
        private void ThreadStartMain()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                A a = new A();
                ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(a.A_GetCounryName);
                Thread t = new Thread(start);
                t.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    class A
    {
        public B GetNewObject()
        {
            B bObj = new B();
            return bObj;
        }

        public void A_GetCounryName()
        { 
            B b=GetObject();
            string cName=b.B_GetCoutryName();
        }
    }

    class B
    {
        C cObj = null;

        public B()
        {
            cObj = new C();
            cObj.Prop1 = 1;
            cObj.Prop1 = 2;
            cObj.Prop1 = 3;
        }

        public string B_GetCoutryName()
        {
           string countryName= cObj.C_GetCoutryName();
           return countryName;
        }
    }


    class C
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        public int Prop2 { get; set; }
        public int Prop3 { get; set; }

        public string C_GetCoutryName()
        {
            string name = "Italy";
            return name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is safe because your threads do not share state. More precisely: They do not access common storage locations.

Comment: Is this because of i am creating new instance always and accessing it's methods.

Comment: Yes. Each new instance has its own data independent of all other instances.